# Using a private link to connect to on-premises host

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

Can a AWS Direct connection be replaced with a Private link to connect to an on-premises host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **AWS Direct Connect** connection uses a fiber-optic cable over communications networks to connect on-premises equipment to AWS.

A **Private Link** connection attaches a VPC to services **within the AWS network infrastructure** that have been exposed/published via Private Link.

They are not interchangeable.